# Fixing SMD joystick button to PCB

Tags: pcb, kicad, button, joystick

I have ordered some of these small joystick buttons and I'm not sure if they will be properly fixed just with the 6 soldering points, as you do some latteral pressure to action them.

[image]

If I create a custom footprint in Kicad I could consider these two plastic knobs below, or remove them, and do something with the metallic wings. I'm not sure what would be better or possible.
Any ideas or recommendations?

I have ordered also these ones, through hole:

[image]

I can try with both, are very cheap anyway, but I'm not sure how should it be properly designed in Kicad.  I have all the measures from the aliexpress vendor.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intention is to have the two holes on PCB where the two plastic pins go into for mechanical support, and the intention for the two metal wings of the case is to solder them to the PCB for mechanical support.

Comment: Ok. So I can create the footprint with the holes and two additional pads to solder the wings, and it should be strong enough. Ok, thanks!